# Does cloud9 ide have a ruby on rails server side debugger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, railstutorial.org, cloud9-ide

I am investigating using cloud9 as the ide for a college ruby on rails class. I am trying to get the debugger to work but can't figure it out. I appear to be able to set a breakpoint via a gutter click (I get the red dot etc) but I don't get a break when the app hits that point. The doco says I should be setting "run with debug" in the run panel settings, but I can't see that option anywhere. Has anyone successfully run a server side debug session w ruby on rails in C9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFIK, cloud9 IDE does not have a ruby debugger.  According to their [documentation](https://docs.c9.io/running_and_debugging_code.html), the debugger only support javascript/node.js apps:

```
Note: Currently, only Javascript/Node.js applications can make use of the debugger.
```

Hopefully, I'm wrong, and they've implemented it for ruby.

Comment: Argg, I skipped straight down to the debugging section, missed that bit at the top. This is a rather fatal flaw for what is otherwise a really excellent tool. Such a pity :(

Comment: FWIW: I'm with you.  I've been test-driving it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add the result of some more investigation after accepting the built in Cloud9 debugger wouldn't work. It turns out that the standard terminal based debugger, byebug, does actually work in Cloud9. Not as handy as a GUI debugger buts lets you get at all the standard things you'd want out of a server side debugger so it's grand for now. See

[Debugging rails applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html)

for details. Don't forget to install the byebug gem.